# Left recursive rules of Xtext

Tags: recursion, antlr, grammar, xtext

I faced a recursive rule problem in Xtext. The simplified version is as follow:

```
grammar my.mavenized.HeroLanguage with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate heroLanguage "http://www.mavenized.my/HeroLanguage"

Atomic:
    Map |
    FunctionCall |
    value=ID;

Map:
    'map' '{'
        (entries+=MapEntry)+
    '}';

MapEntry:
    '(' key=Atomic ')' '=>' value=Atomic;

FunctionCall:
    name=ID '(' arg=Atomic ')';
```

And Xtext gives me this error message:

```
[fatal] rule ruleAtomic has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 2,3.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

But i cannot find left recursive problems. Is there some implicit rules in Xtext about the left recursive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You `Map` contains a list of `MapEntry`s which end with an `Atomic`. An `Atomic` in turn is either a `FunctionCall` or a plain `ID`. The Tail of a `FunctionCall` looks like the beginning of the next `MapEntry`, though. Since that tail is infinitely deep nested, it is not possible to decide which path to follow. That's what your error message stems from. You could use a predicate to convince the parser about on or the other path to go, e.g.

```
FunctionCall:
  name=ID =>'(' arg=Atomic ')' 
;
```

If that is not possible for your use case, you may want to enable backtracking, though that's not recommended.

Comment: I tried to add a predicate as your suggestion, but it still throws fatal warning of recursive. I think that the second part of `FunctionCall` as end of `MapEntry` cannot be treated as the next start since in that way the next key token cannot be consumed. An example is like `map { (a) => f(b) (c) => d }`.